# getting Unknown permission error of AUTHORIZE_SERVICE

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

I have integrated facebook in my app. Application running in Device Gallexy 2.3 but app is not running in Device SonyEricsson compatible with 4.0.3 and genarating Exception

Unknown permission `com.sonyericsson.facebook.permission.AUTHORIZE_SERVICE` in package `com.sonyericsson`

Answer (score 0):

Synch your device with facebook account.